# How to execute a procedure that has OUT parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I created this procedure in order to join two tables and select data. The base sql statement works as intended

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE task1
(p_task1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_task1 FOR
    SELECT Department.D#, Department.DNAME, Employee.D#, Employee.Name
    FROM Department JOIN Employee ON
    Employee.D# = Department.D#;
END task1;
/
```

However, when I use the command `EXECUTE task1` in SQL*Plus, I receive this error:

```
SQL> EXECUTE task1;
BEGIN task1; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TASK1'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I did some research into the error and its linked to parameters but im unsure what parameters i need, I didn't even intend on coding my procedure to take a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have an OUT parameter... but still a parameter, in you procedure you have declared the parameter as

**(p_task1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)**

So when you call task1 you need to provide a location for it to put the output (OUT parameter)

so in your terminal you would have something along the lines of the below....

```
execute declare ref_cur SYS_REFCURSOR; begin task1(ref_cur); end;
```

In the above line we have added **declare ref_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;** which allows you to access the data the procedure fetches.

However a this stage you are just fetching the data and then doing nothing with it.  Once retrieved you will need to iterate through the ref_cursor and do whatever it is you need to do with it.

Comment: do i puts in the terminal or my procedure?

Comment: @NickJam I have updated my answer to try and make it clearer.  Hopefully you find this helpful